# Parenthesis edit in emacs for python

Tags: python-2.7, emacs, elpy

I am using the elpy package on emacs for using python. Is there a possibility to have something like Paredit to close parentheses and brackets for python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that I'm not very familiar with Python, I'd say try [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) first.  It's highly configurable, and if you load the `smartparens-config` module (i.e., `(require 'smartparens-config)`), it will automatically set up defaults for each programming language it supports (including Python) that are usually pretty decent.

In my opinion, the big advantage `smartparens` seems to have over things like `paredit` is that it's flexible enough to be useful in most programming modes and even non-programming modes, so you can set up a common interface for everything you do.

Answer (score 2):

For specifically closing brackets (`])}`), you can try [general-close](https://github.com/emacs-berlin/general-close).

For automatically pairing brackets, there are many options; start at by looking at [autopairs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs) on the Emacs wiki.

Comment: How can i use it, what should i put in my init.el?

Comment: The easiest way is to set up Melpa (https://melpa.org/#/getting-started), install it, then bind a key like `(global-set-key (kbd ";") 'global-close)`.  Beware that some major (or minor) modes may override the `;` binding.

Comment: I have done `M-x package-install general-close`, and put your keybinding in my init.el. Is that right? But i still don't get closed paranthesis by typing `(`. What have you bound to ";"? If i hit the ; i see: `Symbols function definition is void: global-close`

Comment: "function definition is void" means Emacs doesn't know about the function.  Usually, user-visible functions are "autoloaded", which means that Emacs knows they exist and loads the relevant file on demand the first time they're invoked.  `general-close` should be autoloaded, but the library author neglected to do that.  You can fix that by doing `(require 'general-close)` to load the library.

Comment: `general-close` only closes brackets, it doesn't open them.  It makes it so you only have to type one key to close any type of bracket.  It sounds like you actually want opening brackets to automatically type the closing bracket, which is not exactly what you asked for.  There are many ways to do that in Emacs, I'd try searching a bit for that.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am looking for: want opening brackets to automatically type the closing bracket